# Show and then fade element with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 3 with the transitions module includes some utility classes for animating the showing and hiding of elements via fade. When you have an element with a class of fade, its opacity is 0. Then when you add the class "in" to it, it animates to opacity to 1.

The problem with this is that the element is not `display:none`, so it takes up space.

Bootstrap also includes the utility class "hide" which does the `display:none` part for you. Here is a sample of a fully-hidden element in HTML, using these utility classes:

```
<div id="sample" class="hide fade">
  Originally hidden and faded out, then shown and faded in
</div>
```

In theory you should be able to un-hide (convert to block) and then fade in, like this:

```
$('#sample').removeClass('hide').addClass('in');
```

However, this doesn't work. There's something about the internal timing of the browser. I'm not sure what. The net result is that the element is shown, but there is no fade animation. Or at least in Chrome; I'll admit I didn't test other browsers because this needs to work in Chrome anyhow.

Now, I DO have a solution. I delay the adding of 'in' by a brief moment. This causes it to work appropriately:

```
var $sample = $('#sample');
$sample.removeClass('hide');
setTimeout(function() {$sample.addClass('in')}, 100);
```

Heck, I can even abstract this as a utility function and be done with it. But there's the overly-curious (and pedantic) part of me that wonders if this hack is necessary, or if I'm missing something. Does anybody see a better and non-hacky-feeling way of doing this?

Here's a jsfiddle (some markup changes to allow both test cases at once): https://jsfiddle.net/pmd6ow7r/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not animate display:none item because it is been ignored by parsing engine. What you can do instead of a timeout function is not to use display:none, but instead hide the element with height:0 like shown in the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/pmd6ow7r/3/

so basically you don't use hide bootstrap class and use your custom lets say custom-hide

```
.custom-hide {
   height:0;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I like it and will give it a try. However, it's not the display:none that's being animated. It's the opacity. Which CAN be animated, as shown in the fiddle I provided. In theory, the chain removes the display:none altogether (leaving it as display:block) and THEN animates opacity. Not display value. In theory it works and some past discussions recommend that exact chain, but something has changed that creates some sort of unexpected internal race condition (or something) causing the chain to fail.

Comment: Opacity can be animated but when the dom element is display:none it is not rendered at all thus none of its properties can be animated because they don't exist. When you make it display:block it needs more time to render than your script needs to add the class. So the animation fails.

Comment: ^^ makes sense, Gurami! Alas, the technique itself doesn't work because the container's height of 0 doesn't prevent the contents from taking up space.

Comment: Or I should say-- the technique isn't one-size fits-all. With plain divs it seems to work. My "hidden" area contains all manner of content, and somehow, some of its formatting is making it such that the container doesn't hide. There are various elements (forms, labels) with various types of display (table) and other settings (box-sizing). I haven't determined which exactly is causing layout, but suffice it to say the container is indeed height 0 but the contents are taking space.

Comment: I did find it by accident, after all -- it's float (of course!). If you have floated content, it is allowed to take up space even though it's "inside" the container. We've all seen this before by accident when we've had to give our containers layout with the overflow property. In the case of Bootstrap, the grid system uses float.

Comment: You should make overflow:hidden to height:0, sorry i forgot to mention it, this way the contents inside will not be able to take space if the container is height:0; This way it becomes the only all fit workaround to the display:none problem as far as i know

Comment: Yup, works! You should add the overflow:hidden into your sample code so that if anyone else finds this answer, it will be immediately apparent. :)

Answer (score 4):

Keep it visible as it is, but hide it using jQuery...

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#sample")
            .hide() // hides it first, or style it with 'display: none;' instead
            .fadeIn(300) // fades it in
            .delay(3260) // (optionally) waits
            .fadeOut(300); // (optionally) fades it out
    });
</script>
```